# I was advised not to use reflection here... Why not?

Tags: java, reflection

This code is used to sort a List.  The list could contain in the thousands of elements but less than 10k.

```
protected <E> int compareFields(E o1, E o2, String fieldName){
    try { 
        Comparable o1Data = (Comparable) o1.getClass().getMethod(fieldName).invoke(o1);
        Comparable o2Data = (Comparable) o2.getClass().getMethod(fieldName).invoke(o2);
        return o1Data == null ? o2Data == null ? 0 : 1 :
               o2Data == null ? -1 : o1Data.compareTo(o2Data);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I was advised to

> "Please don't use reflection for things like this!!
>   Either supply the method with a suitable Comparator, or a method to extract the relevant property (may be computed in a way not supported by the original type), or both."

An example of a better way to do this would be nice.

Context:
I've got many screens with data tables.  Each one is build from a List.  Each data table needs to be sortable by each of its 6 columns.  The columns are either Date or String.

Comment: What is the context? Sorting of a dataset?

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut Yes, I'm sorting and the list could be in the 1000s.

Comment: Well the posted comment already tells you what to do instead. And I wholeheartedly agree: If you can change the code (which the writer of the note seems to assume as well), doing this thing by reflection is not only inefficient but horrible code to maintain as well (and really fragile).

Comment: Is there _any_ reason you pass the method name as a String?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen I guess the reason is that this is my first use of reflection and I'm not aware of a better way to do it.

Comment: @Dale have a look at `Comparator` and use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using reflection here will potentially be much slower, as you are adding number of stack frames to each comparison by using `getClass`, `getMethod` and `invoke` rather than using the objects' native compare method.

Ideally, you would write the method to avoid the use of `object` in the signature.  A "suitable Comparator" would at least be strongly bound to the objects' type (which you assume are the same).  If you must have dynamic field comparison (as it appears), then at least the reflection could be encapsulated in that comparator.

If you are going to call this thousands of times, though, it would be best to pre-bind a Comparator to the field you are sorting by.  This way, you only call `getMethod` once up front, rather than once for each individual comparison.

Comment: OP is comparing objects by their properties, which are `Comparable`. Whether the objects itself implement `Comparable` is irrelevant if there is a need to sort them by more than one criteria. The idea is probably to allow dynamic sorting, in a datagrid for example.

Comment: reflection probably also has to do some security checks and whatnot. Especially on older JVMs reflection was horribly slow in general and while it has gotten better, it still makes optimizations for the JIT pretty hard (e.g. presumably no inlining). So yes most certainly more than a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a good example without context, so for now here's a small list of why it's not the best idea:

1. The field provided has no guarantee of being Comparable (not sure why the code here needs to catch that exception and rebrand it).
2. What if the type of objects provided are not meant to be compared in this way? (It's an overly generic method name to know how it's supposed to be used).
3. It's not strongly typed. Providing the field name as a string means you'll have to change your code everywhere whenever the property name changes, and it'll be hard to track down where you need to make those changes.
4. Reflection is potentially slower than if implemented in a strongly typed manner.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers described well why it is not advised to use reflection. I want to add an example using a more conventional solution.

Instead of specifying the field that is used to compare the two objects, you should take a `Comparator` instance as an argument. This way the client who uses this method can specify how to compare the two objects.

```
protected <E> int compareFields(E o1, E o2, Comparator<E> comparator) {
    return comparator.compare(o1, o2);
}
```

And an example call to this function would look like this:

```
MyClass a = ...;
MyClass b = ...;
Comparator<MyClass> intFieldComparator = new Comparator<MyClass> {
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        int field1 = o1.getIntField();
        int field2 = o2.getIntField();

        return field2 - field1;
    }
};

compareFields(a, b, intFieldComparator);
```

You can define different comparators if you want to compare the objects using several fields.