# Reference member by parameter name?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class ASDF {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}

ASDF[] myArray;
```

And an array of ASDF of some size. Is there any way to write a function that accepts the name of a member of ASDF, and the array of ASDF, and sums all members of the given member name?

ie, I would want a function that would work like this:

```
sumMember(myArray, a);
```

would return the sum of all 'a' member variables in ASDF. There are much more than three member variables though, so having a function for each isn't realistic.

Comment: You can accomplish this using reflection

Comment: Instead of defining a large number of member variables, define one member [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) with a name as the key.

Answer (score 6):

You could use reflection or a map or...

Alternatively, if you can use Java 8, you could pass a lambda to point to the member that you are interested in. It is not as short as what you wanted, but not too bad either:

```
public static int sumMembers(ASDF[] array, ToIntFunction<ASDF> member) {
  return Arrays.stream(array).mapToInt(member).sum();
}
```

Sample use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ASDF[] array = {new ASDF(), new ASDF()};
  array[0].a = 1;
  array[1].a = 2;

  //THIS IS HOW YOU CALL IT
  int sum = sumMembers(array, a -> a.a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the class and fields are `public` then you can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html) to get field values by name, so you could write a `sumMember` such that

```
sumMember(myArray, "a");
```

works.

[Reflection tends to be overpowered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885192/i-was-advised-not-to-use-reflection-here-why-not) and interfers with static-analysis tools like refactorings, so you could abstract over a field using an `interface Getter` as in

```
public interface Getter<V, O> {
  V get(O source);
}

public static <O>
double sumMember(Iterable<? extends O> toSum, Getter<Double, O> getter) {
  double runningSum = 0.0;
  for (O o : toSum) { runningSum += getter(toSum); }
  return runningSum;
}
```

and then use it thus

```
sumMember(Arrays.asList(yourArray),  // Xlate btw array and Iterable
          new Getter<Double, ASDF>() {  // ASDF x -> x.a
            public Double get(ASDF asdf) { return asdf.a; }
          });
```

or use a Java8 lambda to create the getter.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally considered poor design practice to put public fields in a class.  If the class has a manageable number of members, all `int`, then it's best to make the fields `private` and add getter functions for each field:

```
class ASDF {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public int getB() { ... and so on
}
```

(I'm assuming you would have better names for these fields.)  If that's the case, then you can use Java 8's member function syntax to write a `sum` function easily that takes one of the functions as a parameter:

```
int sumMember(ASDF[] array, toIntFunction<ASDF> func) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (ASDF element : array) {
         sum += func.applyAsInt(element);
    }
    return sum;
}

sumA = sumMember(myArray, ASDF::getA);
sumB = sumMember(myArray, ASDF::getB);
```

and so on.  `ToIntFunction` is in `java.util.function`, and its description is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html).  [Also, using a lambda as in assylias' answer works too and is pretty simple to write; in that case you can solve it without the getter functions, but I still think it's a bad idea to use public fields in this way.]

However, if there are a large number of `int` members, or if you have a class whose only purpose is to hold a number of `int` members (i.e. no methods other than getters or setters), then you probably don't want individual members.  Instead, you want a class that uses an array or some sort of collection to hold the members, so that could can access the members by a `String` name or some other sort of key or index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to reference by field name,
but that is a terrible idea.

Instead,
create a class that knows the value you want and returns it to the sumMember method.

Here is some code:

```
public int sumMember(
    final ASDF[] itIsTerribleToUseArraysLikeThis
    final ValueRetriever valueRetriever)
{
    int returnValue = 0;

    for (ASDF current : itIsTerribleToUseArraysLikeThis)
    {
        returnValue += valueRetriever.getValue(current);
    }

    return returnValue;
}

public interface ValueRetriever
{
    public int getValue(ASDF structure);
}

public class AValueRetriever implements ValueRetriever
{
    public int getValue(final ASDF structure)
    {
        if (structure != null)
        {
            return structure.a;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

sumMember(myArray, new AValueRetriever());
```

Note:
Your code is terrible in several ways.

1. ASDF is a structure.  This is fine if you are writing code in C or some other non-oo language.  In Java, it is terrible.  Use objects.
2. Passing arrays around is also terrible.  Java (and other oo languages) provide nice implementations of collections.  Use these.  Check out [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)